# learn python the hard way exercise 20 i dont understans how it increments the line numbers 1, 2, 3

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: `current_line = current_line + 1` ?

Comment: I don't understand how it increments the line numbers 1, 2, 3, i everything else is clear to me, il appreciate if someone could answer this please, than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value of `current_line` is `1`. When you call, `current_line = current_line + 1`, we first evaluate what's on the right hand side of the `=`. That is `current_line + 1`, which gives `2`. Now `2` gets assigned to the variable on the left of `=`, which is `current_line`. So now `current_line` is `2`! The old value of `current_line` (`1`) gets overwritten.